# JpaRepositoryFactoryBean has wrong entitymanager

Tags: spring, datasource, entitymanager

the given entitymanager has no managedtype for my class, it is the wrong entitymanager.

i thought that by simply defining the model and repository scan to the specific namespace does handle this automatically, but as it seems i am wrong (?!). Does anybody know how to handle this problem?

He has the class something.application.model.User but uses the entitymanager with the managedtypes of the namespace something.manager.model.

```
public class JpaConfiguration {

@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "something.application.model" })
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "something.application.model" }, repositoryFactoryBeanClass = RepositoryFactoryBean.class, entityManagerFactoryRef = "applicationEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "applicationTransactionManager")
public static class ApplicationJpaConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    /**
     * The datasource used by the system. Configuration see
     * /src/main/resources/application.properties.
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean(name="applicationDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.application.datasource")
    public DataSource applicationDataSource() {
        return new TenantAwareDataSource();
    }

    /**
     * The transaction manager used by the application system. 
     * 
     * @param javax.sql.DataSource applicationDataSource
     * @param javax.sql.DataSource loadTimeWeaver
     * @return org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean(name="applicationTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager applicationTransactionManager(LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(applicationEntityManagerFactory(loadTimeWeaver).getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * The entity manager factory used by application system. Specific properties of the
     * persistence provider eclipselink are configured here.
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean(name="applicationEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean applicationEntityManagerFactory(LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver) {

        Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "create-or-extend-tables");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.session.customizer", HistoryBuildingSessionCustomizer.class.getName());
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.level.sql", "fine");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.parameters", "true");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.temporal.mutable", "true");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode", "commit");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.cache.shared.default", "false");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.query-results-cache", "false");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.target-database", "MySQL");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(applicationDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setLoadTimeWeaver(loadTimeWeaver);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("applicationPersistenceUnit");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * A support object that wraps all available repositories and has some
     * convenience functions.
     */
    @Bean
    public Repositories repositories() {
        return new Repositories(applicationContext);
    }
}


@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "something.manager.model" })
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "something.manager.model" }, repositoryFactoryBeanClass = RepositoryFactoryBean.class, entityManagerFactoryRef = "managerEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "managerTransactionManager")
public static class ManagerJpaConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    /**
     * The datasource used by the system. Configuration see
     * /src/main/resources/application.properties.
     */
    @Bean(name="managerDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.manager.datasource")
    public DataSource managerDataSource() {
        return new BasicDataSource();
    }

    /**
     * The transaction manager used by the manager system. 
     * 
     * @param javax.sql.DataSource managerDataSource
     * @param javax.sql.DataSource loadTimeWeaver
     * @return org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager
     */
    @Bean(name="managerTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager managerTransactionManager(DataSource managerDataSource, LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(managerEntityManagerFactory(managerDataSource, loadTimeWeaver).getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * The entity manager factory used by manager system. Specific properties of the
     * persistence provider eclipselink are configured here.
     */
    @Bean(name="managerEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean managerEntityManagerFactory(DataSource managerDataSource, LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver) {

        Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "create-or-extend-tables");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.session.customizer", HistoryBuildingSessionCustomizer.class.getName());
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.level.sql", "fine");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.parameters", "true");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.temporal.mutable", "true");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode", "commit");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.cache.shared.default", "false");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.query-results-cache", "false");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.target-database", "MySQL");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(managerDataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setLoadTimeWeaver(loadTimeWeaver);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * A support object that wraps all available repositories and has some
     * convenience functions.
     */
    @Bean
    public Repositories repositories() {
        return new Repositories(applicationContext);
    }
}
```

}